# How can a make a sprite in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game player thing where you can play multiple games on python. I made a tkinter window for the games but I can't figure out how to put a turtle or sprite or whatever on it.

code:

```
def game1():
    gamewd = Tk()
    gamewd.geometry("1500x900")
game1()
```

I want to add a sprite to the above^^^

Comment: Research the `Canvas` widget. You can add and move images on it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you :)

Here is an example of sprites being used:

```
tomato = PhotoImage(file='tomato.png')

lbl1 = Label(text='Timer', fg=GREEN, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 50, 'bold'))
lbl1.grid(column=1, row=0)

canv = Canvas(width=200, height=224, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
canv.create_image(100, 112, image=tomato)
timer_txt = canv.create_text(100, 130, text='00:00', fill='white', font=(FONT_NAME, 30, 'bold'))
canv.grid(column=1, row=1)

btn1 = Button(text='Start', highlightthickness=0, command=start_timer)
btn1.grid(column=0, row=2)

playpausebtn = Button(text='Pause', highlightthickness=0, command=playpause, state=DISABLED)
playpausebtn.grid(column=1, row=2)

btn2 = Button(text='Reset', highlightthickness=0, command=reset_timer, state=DISABLED)
btn2.grid(column=2, row=2)

lbl2 = Label(fg=GREEN, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 20, 'normal'))
lbl2.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=20)
```

This is a code extract from a Pomodoro program I make a few months ago.

If you want to make a simple sprite with 1 item only (a monosprite), like an image, button or label, be sure to check the [tkinter basic widgets](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html).

However, if you want to make a sprite with many different parts (i.e. a polysprite) though, you may use the [tkinter.Canvas](https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-canvas/#:%7E:text=A%20tkinter%20canvas%20can%20be,ovals%2C%20polygons%2C%20and%20rectangles.) widget, as you see in my code example.